# how to validate dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have cascading dropdown to display report.its working fine but for 2nd dropdown its display 1st dropdown report and then 2nd dropdown report and its continues for other dropdowns.

I think if conditions are becoming true for all the time so i am getting reports for all

Please tell whats wrong:

```
 $("#SearchDialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 450,
        height: 'auto',
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        position: { my: "right top", at: "right top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "Search": function () {

                var selected = $('#SearchDialogTabs').tabs('option', 'active');
                //var filter = "";

                if (selected == 0) {
                    var DistrictName = $('#ddlDistrict').val();
                    var TalukName = $('#ddlTaluk').val();
                    var HobliName = $('#ddlHobli').val();
                    var VillageName = $('#ddlVillage').val();

                    if ((DistrictName.length != 0) && (TalukName = '-- Select --')) {



                        if (($('#ddlDistrict').val() == '-- Select --')) {
                            alert("Please Select District");
                            $("#SearchDialogTabs").tabs({ selected: 0 });
                            $("#SearchDialog").dialog('open');
                        }

                        GetDistrictReport($('#ddlDistrict>option:selected').val());

                    }


                    if ((DistrictName.length != 0) && (TalukName = $('#ddlTaluk').val()) && (HobliName = '-- Select --')) {

                        if (($('#ddlTaluk').val() == '-- Select --')) {
                            alert("Please Select Taluk");
                            $("#SearchDialogTabs").tabs({ selected: 0 });
                            $("#SearchDialog").dialog('open');
                        }


                        GetTalukReport($('#ddlTaluk>option:selected').val());

                    }



                    if (($('#ddlHobli').val() == '-- Select --')) {
                        alert("Please Select Hobli");
                        $("#SearchDialogTabs").tabs({ selected: 0 });
                        $("#SearchDialog").dialog('open');
                    }

                    if ((DistrictName.length != 0) && (TalukName.length != 0) && (HobliName.length != 0)) {
                        GetHobliReport($('#ddlHobli>option:selected').val());
                    }


                    if (($('#ddlVillage').val() == '-- Select --')) {
                        alert("Please Select Village");
                        $("#SearchDialogTabs").tabs({ selected: 0 });
                        $("#SearchDialog").dialog('open');
                    }

                    if ((DistrictName.length != 0) && (TalukName.length != 0) && (HobliName.length != 0) && (VillageName.length != 0)) {
                        GetVillageReport($('#ddlVillage>option:selected').val());
                    }
                }                 

        },
          Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
    });
```

Comment: Add a fiddle to ease the testing for us.

Comment: ($('#ddlHobli').val() == '-- Select --') this might be something, not sure if this is the default value